# How can I upload .hex files to a Pro Micro using Linux?

Tags: avrdude

I have a hand-wired keyboard that uses a Pro Micro board, with an ATmega32u4 chip. I can't seem to flash firmware on it. The commands I've been trying are variations of:

```
avrdude -p m32U4 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c avr109 -U flash:w:atreus62.hex
```

The errors I've been getting begin:

```
Writing | #######avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
####avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: write block
 ***failed;  
 ***failed;  
 ***failed;  
 ***failed;
```

And end:

```
#avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
#avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
# | 100% 0.16s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x0d != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader
```

I'm on Arch Linux. Any ideas?

Comment: Enable verbose mode, program it once with the IDE, and copy the command line it uses.

Comment: What is the IDE?

Comment: And what do you mean by "program it"? Could you just tell me what the avrdude command is? I don't have any IDE installed.

Comment: Also verbose modes -v, -vv, -vvv, and -vvvv don't really seem to affect anything.

Comment: You are asking a question on the Arduino site, presumably you are familiar with the Arduino tools?  If not, give that a try first to validate your hardware and tools setup (before you try to do things the hard way.  Use the avrdude and configuration file for it that ships with a modern Arduino IDE version, and let the IDE drive it the first time, with verbose mode selected in the dropdown menu, so you see the suitable command.

Comment: I have no idea what the Arduino IDE is all about, but I installed it, and can't really make heads or tails of it. How can I open a hex file with it? If I could get the IDE to program the board, that'd be fine, too, but I have no idea what's going on in this program.

Comment: Also the IDE doesn't seem to have my board listed (pro micro).

Comment: @Jon, how did you create the hex file? ... it is odd that you would not know what an IDE is.

Comment: Using QMK. I know what an IDE is, just not what the Arduino IDE is supposed to do with .hex files, or how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

There's two stages to uploading a hex file to a USB-based Arduino - and you're only doing the second stage.

The first stage is to reset the board into the bootloader so it can accept the instructions from the second stage.  The IDE normally does that manually for you when you hit the UPLOAD button.

The way these boards are reset is to first open the CDC/ACM port and set the baud rate to 1200, then close the port again. That triggers the code to reset the board into the bootloader.

You can probably do it using the `stty` tool in Linux:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 speed 1200
$ stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 speed 115200
$ avrdude -p m32U4 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c avr109 -U flash:w:atreus62.hex
```

The second `stty` may not actually be needed, but it's good to reset the baud rate to a normal value ready for uploading. I don't have a board to hand right now to test it though.

Comment: Those commands don't seem to help, sadly. They both return `9600`, if that's at all helpful. I'm still getting "programmer did not respond" errors.

Comment: The return value is the value it was before changing it. The second should return 1200 not 9600.  You can try using `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ospeed 1200 ispeed 1200` instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help either, I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you had it working in the IDE at all?

Comment: I'm at a loss for how to upload .hex files to a chip using the IDE. (And furthermore the IDE is almost totally useless to me, since the UI isn't HiDPI-friendly.)

Comment: You don't upload hex files with the IDE. You write code, compile it, and upload that. Try the Blink example.

Comment: @Jon The point of the IDE and the reason we're all harping on it is that success in using the IDE's automation to upload trivial example code you aren't interested in shows you the commands you can then use to upload your custom hex file.  It lets you benefit from the work someone else put into figuring out how to do this, rather than having to figure it out again from scratch.  There's more wrong than right with the Arduino IDE when it comes to actual software development, but what it is good at is getting trivial code into a chip without spending a day reading documentation.

Comment: Also it confirms that your board is actually working and able to accept code. Some cheap chinese clones come without a bootloader.

Comment: If I can't upload hex files with the IDE, though, how can I use it? The codebase that generates my hex files is fairly complex, and scattered in a bunch of files across QMK. There's a real network of includes, env vars, and makefile instructions that I, as a non-C programmer, can't make sense of. Trying to put this all together in a way that the IDE will understand seems incredibly complicated. So I think everyone's advice to use the IDE is well-intentioned, but it won't help me just get this already-compiled hex file onto my board, which should be a simple task.

Comment: We're not telling you to use the IDE to complete your task. We are telling you to use the IDE to test that the board and everything is functional. Once that is confirmed we can then move on to more low-level things.

Comment: @Majenko you just saved my day, thank you! Couldn't get QMK to flash to my pro micro using any of the normal tooling, but setting `ospeed` and `ispeed` explicitly caused it to magically work. For the record I'm on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was caused by udev, I found the answer [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-32u4-adalogger/using-with-arduino-ide)

[It's some obscure bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/1473246)

Tweaking udev rules solved the problem for me, now all is good, here is the procedure: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-ide-setup/linux-setup#udev-rules

Comment: Had the same issue, and this fixed it for me! (mostly - I still had to use the `stty` commands from Majenko's answer, and run the upload a couple of times in order to get it working... but it worked!) It's a bit difficult to find this answer...